# Get command line arguments while listening to Vnode Scope of KEXT

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

Basically I am creating a kext which can monitor the processes. The following are the goals.

1. Observe process creation ---> Currently using vnode scope as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2127/_index.html
2. Based on the user policies, allow or deny permission. Requires the path of the executable, command line args, parent pid and parent path to take a decision ----> Managed to get executable path, parent process name(instead of full path).
3. Notification when the process exits ---> Currently, have a user land process, have managed to get the exit notification in the user land using kqueue. Would be great if I can get kext callbacks to listen instead of user land dependency.

So far I have come across a blog where they have managed to get command line arguments [macf policy based kext where command line args are retrived](https://www.fortinet.com/blog/threat-research/monitoring-macos--part-i--monitoring-process-execution-via-macf.html). The problem in Mac policy is private API and is deprecated for non-apple kexts.

The following are the unsolved problems I currently have. Help / pointer would be great

I need help to get access command line arg

1. Retrive command line arguments, in vnode scope of kauth listener
2. Process exit listener callbacks for the kext

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Notifications from the KAuth framework (both VNode & File scope) occur too early in the life of process creation to retrieve cmd line args at this time, so you won't be able to make a VNode allow / deny decision, based on this criteria in monitoring the exec of a process.

Comment: Thank you @TheDarkKnight . Thank you for confirming the behaviour which I had observed. Since, I expect the OS to capture and contain this information somewhere as it needs to be set in the proc struct, was having some hopes to be able to gather that information.

Comment: You can get the info, just not at the time of the VNode scope notification

Comment: I have noticed that vode listener will call exec action every time the process is performing a system call to some other process. For example: Say I write a c program, with system("echo hello") in loop. I launched this c Program, it got a pid, say 300. Every time it does that system call, I get pid as 300 and vnode path as path to the c program executable. The shell for the system with different pid also gets called. Just was wondering if there was a way to identify that this process was already launched.

Comment: This is outside of the scope of the original question. I suggest starting a new question with the relevant details.